# Django QuerySet monkey patching to add a new attribute to returned models

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, monkeypatching

I am using Django 3.2.

I have a model like this:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    last_valid_field_values = models.TextField(help_text='JSON field of fieldnames and values')
    # ...
```

I want to be able to monkey patch my queries, so that when fetching `MyModel` instances, I can added an attribute `last_values_dict` — which is just the loaded JSON of the `last_valid_field_values`.

So I would have something like this (pseudocode):

```
def callback_func(instance):
    instance.last_values_dict = json.loads(instance.last_valid_field_values)
    
    
MyModel.objects.all().apply_some_function_to_monkey_patch(callback_func)
```

How can I do this? I also think that possibly, this could be done via a generator iterating over the `QuerySet`?

Comment: Why not just make `.last_values_dict()` a method on the model?

Comment: Because it will make things too easy (Doh!). I'm embarrassed that I went for a hack, when an obvious solution was staring me in the face. Still, it would be interesting to see if there is a way to do this - even though my particular use case, is trivially solved by your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass `QuerySet` to implement `apply_some_function_to_monkey_patch` and override `_fetch_all` to run the callback function, similar to how [`QuerySet.prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) is [implemented](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c627226d05dd52aef59447dcfb29cec2c2b11b8a/django/db/models/query.py#L1553). You also need to override `__init__` and `_clone` for it to work with filters.

```py
class MyQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def __init__(self, model=None, query=None, using=None, hints=None):
        super().__init__(model=model, query=query, using=using, hints=hints)
        self._callback_funcs = ()
        self._callback_done = False

    def apply_some_function_to_monkey_patch(self, *callback_funcs):
        qs = self._chain()
        qs._callback_funcs = qs._callback_funcs + callback_funcs
        return qs

    def _callback(self):
        for callback_func in self._callback_funcs:
            for item in self._result_cache:
                callback_func(item)
        self._callback_done = True

    def _clone(self):
        clone = super()._clone()
        clone._callback_funcs = self._callback_funcs[:]
        return clone

    def _fetch_all(self):
        super()._fetch_all()
        if self._callback_funcs and not self._callback_done:
            self._callback()
```

Usage:

```py
class MyManager(BaseManager.from_queryset(MyQuerySet)):
    pass


class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = MyManager()
```

```py
def callback_func(instance):
    instance.last_values_dict = json.loads(instance.last_valid_field_values)
    
    
MyModel.objects.all().apply_some_function_to_monkey_patch(callback_func)
```